# cannot ssh to Google compute engine after fstab change

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I wanted to auto mount a disk to my VM so added the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID="0e9b2dc6-4eb9-47b2-9125-571a1e2aed59"    /media/anExistedfolder   defaults       0 0
```

However after resetting the VM, I cannot connect to the VM anymore. Checked the on-line help and tried to override `fstab` by using following start-script in Metadata, still no luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0"  > /etc/fstab
```

As I'm just testing this VM so it doesn't matter if I lose it but imagine this is a production server that I could not lose, what options would I have?

Comment: Looks like the fstype was missing, no idea if this is relevant. What does the console log say? (Some distributions wait for a answer to mountall.sh failures)

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem type is missing in fstab entry. This is the reason why VM dint came only after reboot

Answer (score 0):

to help whoever is interested, Google compute does provide a console to connect to. In my case I did the following:

1. install Cloud SDK
2. enable console

   ```
   gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]  \
   --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
   ```
3. connect to console and then update fstab

As to the reason, Samudrala is correct, the ext was missing and thanks!